# Accessing a system-property from a Tomcat-container using Java

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

Environment: Java (Java EE), Tomcat container

At work the vast majority of our apps run in a Glassfish-container and (as typical) we have a lot of properties externalized from our apps and injected into our Glassfish-environment via the use of an app.properties file where Glassfish then exposes them to our app by making a standard system call something like this:

```
System.getProperty( "myProp" );
```

We have one particular app, however, than was deployed on a Tomcat-container (and due to the large bureaucracy here, that's not going to change anytime soon); the original author also didn't invest the time to research how to do a similar property-externalization using Tomcat as what is done with Glassfish.  The result is that there are several things in this app where you have to comment-out some lines of code when you deploy it to our test-server and comment-out different lines of code when you deploy it to our production-server.  A real pain, and potential-cause of trouble.

So I'm trying to fix that.
From my research it seems that the way to do this in Tomcat is via Tomcat's `server.xml` file, something like this:

```
 <Environment name="myProp" type="java.lang.String" value="This is my value"/>
```

Then, from what I've read [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/globalresources.html), accessing 'myProp' should be the same thing as accessing an `<env-entry>` in the `web.xml`, so image I have an entry like this:

```
 <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>myOtherProp</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>This is my other value</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
```

Then I have implemented the following code in my `Spring#handleRequestInternal()`:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();

String myProp = "<not found>";
try {
      myProp = (String) ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env/myProp" );  // from Tomcat's server.xml
} catch( Exception e ) { ... }

String myOtherProp = "<not found>";
try {
      myOtherProp = (String) ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env/myOtherProp" ); // from web.xml
} catch( Exception e ) { ... }
```

Yet when I log 'myProp' and 'myOtherProp', the one from my web.xml returns the correct value while the one from Tomcat's server.xml is not found (caught by the try/catch).

What gives?
How do I set an environment-variable outside of my app via the Tomcat-container and retrieve it from within my app?

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Gilbert, we are using v5.5 -- I noticed from DataKnife's reference that there is a difference on how to do this between v4 and v6 so I went and looked up v5.5's documentation and found it's the same as v6:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html.  So I'm assuming that I should be following Dataknife's suggestion, is that correct???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting this in server.xml it belongs in the Context.xml file for the servlet containter you're configuring. See [the tomcat Context configuration webpage.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) For more details.

Comment: It took a bit to get this sorted but we finally did.  If you have a recent version of Tomcat (v5.5 or newer) this is the correct answer -- to add an entry to context.xml.  If you have anything older, amol's answer is correct -- to keep it inside the server.xml but move it inside <Context>-tags.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I think of why this is not working is the placement of `<Environment name="myProp" type="java.lang.String" value="This is my value"/>` in server.xml

Try putting the `<Environment name="myProp" type="java.lang.String" value="This is my value"/>` **under the relevant `<Context></Context>`**

Otherwise, your environment variable declaration and lookup code looks Ok.

Comment: *IF* you have an older version of Tomcat (pre v5.5).